# VS Code display compile error messages for clang

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

In atom, when I write any code incorrectly I can view the errors immediately because the file is being scanned by a plugin.

I have the vs code plugin for c/c++ but I do not see this option to display errors. Is this available and I am just failing with my google skills? Or is this not an option with vs code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VSCode plugin for C++ does **not** support "intellisense" at the moment.

It supports debugging and some basic symbol parsing (with code completion) but it doesn't parse your code using a compiler.

For more info: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp